# Using input variables in SQL sent from C# without func/proc

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I am working with a very restrictive Oracle 11g installation, which does not allow me anything but sending a SQL statement. No possibility to create stored procedures or functions. I can't even create a temp table. Other solutions I've seen all recommend how to run the statement interactively or by using procedures and functions.

The statement got pretty complex with lots of parameters in the string being sent. I would like to add some variables to the statement, so that when the statement string is built in C#, the string only need be modified for those variables.

Here is what I mean:

```
sqlStatement = string.format(@"
   declare
      MyVar varchar(15);
   begin
      MyVar := '{0}';
      select * from MyTable where MyCol = MyVar;
   end;
", stringForMyVar);
OdbcDataAdapter oracleAdapter =new OdbcDataAdapter(sqlStatement,_oracleConn);
oracleAdapter.Fill(ds);
```

How can I write the above query so that it returns the resultset from the select?

Comment: Why don't you use parameterized queries?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdataadapter.selectcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Good question. It's not my code and I can't touch the db module. The ODBC code in my example is only for illustration. I must use the custom DatabaseConnector class that executes ODBC and it doesn't use parameters.

Comment: Why are you using `MyVar` in your example code? Why not just substitute the value into the `select` statement itself?

Comment: Because, @Turophile, I want to test the query in Toad and then copy it into my code with minimal changes. The substitution is the way I'm doing it now and I want to make it better.